# How can I create new login in SSMS 2008?

Tags: sql-server

When I attempt to create new login in MSSQL Server 2008, I get the following errors:

[image: error1] [image: error2]

I have tried everything I know, but I can't get it to work.

What should I do and how I can solve these issues?

Comment: Can you please show us the script that was generated for your action? Click the Script button in the New Login window.

Answer (score 4):

Open the Window again to create a new login.  Use the "Search" button to find the Windows login you wish to create an account for.  Then you can click the "Script To" button at the top and get the actual T/SQL Script.  It should look something like

```
CREATE LOGIN [KAWMIN-PC\Classic .NET AppPool] FROM WINDOWS
```

The UI doesn't always work correct for creating logins with spaces or other reserved characters.

Once you have the T/SQL script correct any issues and run the script and the login should be created.  If there is an error post the error message to the site.

Comment: you are wrong, for why heels on this world you recommending  add new user to the Native OS, that against all known good  rulles, never donw-voter then +1

Comment: Denny's answer is NOT suggesting to add a new user to the Native OS. That is a SQL Server create login syntax....

Comment: @Mike Walsh `1)` local user `2)` AD or LDAP (or other WinXxxDomain), not packages

Comment: @mKorbel can you explain your first comment?  I'm not sure what you are saying in that comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would verify that that is a true account you are trying to add. The second error message seems to indicate you may not have the proper account name. I would use the search button and find the local or AD account that way.

The first error appears to say you didn't type a login name in when trying that approach.

You could verify that you are in mixed mode authenticate as mKorbel describes but I think it is more a case of not finding that login or not typing a login name for the other message. The proper place you'd want to go is SSMS --> Right click at the instance level --> Properties --> Security and then you would select SQL and Windows if not selected. My guess is you probably already have that and just need to verify the logins you are using.

Comment: i already had it.But it's still error occurring like above.

Comment: "I already had it" --> what did you already have? Mixed mode authentication? Have you verified that you are using the right login? I really suspect you are likely just typing the login instead of using the search?

Comment: yes!.I had mixed mode.But it's still error like before.